# Add new attribute for the JSON Array List

Tags: javascript, json

I need to add new attribute for JSON object. currently my code like as below

```
 let abc  =  this.dataSource.data;
            console.log(abc);
```

console log data set like below

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 210,
            "temp": "210",
            "city": "colombo",
            "status": "waiting"
        },
        {
             "id": 211,
            "temp": "212",
            "city": "colombo2",
            "status": "waiting"
        },
    ]
}
```

I need to add new attribute for the JSON object. My expect JSON object like below

```
  {
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 210,
            "temp": "210",
            "city": "colombo",
            "status": "waiting"
        "select": false,
        },
        {
             "id": 211,
            "temp": "212",
            "city": "colombo2",
            "status": "waiting",
            "select": false,
        },
    ]
  }
```

I tried to do it using this,

```
abc = {...abc,select:false}
```

but it did not work. How I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `map`:

```js
const data = {
"result": [
    {
        "id": 210,
        "temp": "210",
        "city": "colombo",
        "status": "waiting"
    },
    {
         "id": 211,
        "temp": "212",
        "city": "colombo2",
        "status": "waiting"
    },
]
}
  
  function formatData(data){
    return data.result.map(res=> ({...res, select: false}))
  }

console.log(formatData(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the correct path and iterate over the result array:

```
for (let i=0; i < abc.result.length; i++) {
    abc.result[i].select = false
}
```